# Fixing "module not found" in expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-install, npm-start, npm-package

How to install expo using VS Code integrated Terminal. I installed expo using the command,

```
npm expo-font axios react-native-dotenv
```

I got an error during installation. Then I tried

```
expo --global cli
```

It got installed but when I run command , npm start

I get an error: **"module not found"**.
Then gives some paths to be added to the environment variable which I did add, yet I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To install the above mentioned packages using the command :

```
npm install expo-font react-native-axios react-native-dotenv
```